# Including non-HTML elements in an HTML document

Tags: php, html, css, ruby-on-rails, database

What is meant by including non-HTML elements in an HTML document? Can you provide an example? I know this has something to do with the back-end side of web design being integrated into the front-end, but I'm not sure how to prepare for work that involves doing this.

EDIT:

This "skill" is a bullet point on a job I am applying for and is the only requirement I don't have a full understanding of.

"Be comfortable including non-HTML elements in an HTML template to interact with a CMS."

I'm not sure what I should "learn" to prepare for this.

Comment: what exactly is the context?

Comment: Are you referring to the inclusion of scripts and PHP elements?

Comment: I've updated my post to include a bit more information - sorry if it still isn't enough. I'm kind of in the dark here!

Comment: @DjangMulando that's fine. I'll be honest, based on that bullet point, it seems like whoever wrote the listing doesn't know what's going on either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about decoding marketing speak.

Answer (score 1):

A classic case of HTML/ NON-HTML content in a web page is when we write PHP logic within an HTML file itself and save it as a **.php** file like below (extracted from the PHP website).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

If you observe the normal HTML content also contains the **`<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>';`** contained within it. This is a non HTML element, since the HTML processing engine within the web- browser does not know how to process the  statement.

If you have worked with JSP  - mixing HTML and JSP tags is another example of a mix-up between HTML and non-HTML content.

Ideally, we should avoid mixing HTML and NON-HTML content - this is a poor design practice since it ties up the web page UI( an ever changing aspect) with the relatively stable backend(PHP/JSP code).

The confusion resulting from this poor design practice was what led to the development of mature Model View Controller (MVC) patterns for the web applications.

This is also the reason that templating languages like FTL, Velocity and Django templates came into existence.

Hopefully, this answers your questions and gives you some points of web application design to ponder upon.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you’d provide some information on what you’re trying to achieve, but I think you’re either talking about

- server-side scripts like PHP that are executed on the server and
  never transmitted to the (HTML-interpreting) browser (looks like `<?php ... ?>`), or
- non-standardized HTML-elements like Facebook’s like button code (looks like `<fb:like ...>`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to elements like server-side processed PHP and scripts. When you insert certain tags in an html document like `<?php ... ?>` or `<script>...</script>`, it instructs the server to process everything in-between those tags as either PHP or a script.

```
<?php
/*Your PHP functions go here*/
?>

<script type="javascript">
/*Your javascript functions (i.e. jQuery scripts) go here*/
</script>
```